# Join on Eloquent breaks Relationships?

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-query-builder

I have the following relation:

I have a many-to-many relation between `Course` and `Users`, and then again a has-many relation between `Users` and `Certificates`.

Now here is way how to get all users from one course, who have a certificate in the same course:

```
$user = $course->users()
  ->whereHas('certificates', function ($query) use($course){
         $query->where('course_certificates.course_id', '=', $course->id);
})->first();
```

This will return a user with certificates `$user->certificates`.
This is the query.

```sql
SELECT *
FROM "course_users"
WHERE "course_users"."course_id" = ? AND
    "course_users"."course_id" IS NOT NULL AND
    EXISTS (
        SELECT *
        FROM "course_certificates"
        WHERE "course_users"."id" = "course_certificates"."user_id" AND
        "course_certificates"."course_id" = ?
    )
```

If I use a `join` instead:

```
$user = $course->users()
    ->join('course_certificates', 'course_certificates.user_id', '=', 'course_users.id')
    ->where('course_certificates.course_id', '=', $course->id)
    ->first();
```

Then I get the same user, however the relationship `$user->certificates` is empty?

```sql
SELECT *
FROM "course_users"
INNER JOIN "course_certificates"
    ON "course_certificates"."user_id" = "course_users"."id"
WHERE "course_users"."course_id" = ? AND
    "course_users"."course_id" IS NOT NULL AND
    "course_certificates"."course_id" = ?
```

Why is that?

Comment: I don't expect this to make a difference, but if you eager load `certificates` via `->with('certificates')` on both those queries, does it change anything? At a glance, I can't see why the 2nd approach wouldn't have anything for `$user->certificates`...

Comment: i guess second approach will combine both table data in associative array.but laravel relation return joined table data in separate key like certificates. Second approach like executing queries in mysql.I hope with or wherehas internally mapping based on table fields and generating user friendly result

Comment: In first case, when you are not using join then it is an Eloquent Model. But when you use join, then it becomes query builder and `$user->certificates` does not work.

Comment: @MuhammadInaamMunir That's incorrect; `get_class(User::joins(...)->first())` returns `App\Models\User`. Since the source of the query is `$course->users()`, it will be a model when executed. If you use `DB::` statements, then it's a `stdClass` when executed.

Comment: @TimLewis eager loading does not make a difference

Comment: @Adam I figured it wouldn't, worth a shot though. I just tried this locally, with one of my Models/Relationships, and it worked just fine, so it's something unique with your setup. Maybe consider including your Models, Relationships and/or Schemas?

Comment: @TimLewis I will also try to create this example from scratch, maybe it has something to do with my version, I am on Laravel 5.6

Comment: Hmm potentially, I tested on Laravel 6.x. If you can recreate something, ping me and I can test on 6.x and 8.x; see if it's an issue with your version or something else.

Comment: Not clear, you wrote 2 many-to-name relation with users but have alse a pivot table between courses & certificates. Can you share your test code (on github) to reproduce exactlly what you did.

Comment: @Dri372 sorry the second relation is a hasMany.

Comment: hasManyThrough ?

Answer (score 0):

I am not 100% sure, but if you use `join` I think laravel do not understand whatever table you are joining it with that it is a relation, it is just a join, it could mean anything, but the first query you are telling it what the relation means (`whereHas` some data for X relation).

---

Looking at the source code, I can confirm what I am saying: [`join`](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/6c8371351a4d498eee273dbaa4a3b7182335a463/src/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.php#L456-L483) and [`whereHas`](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/6c8371351a4d498eee273dbaa4a3b7182335a463/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Concerns/QueriesRelationships.php#L145-L148) (and [`has`](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/6c8371351a4d498eee273dbaa4a3b7182335a463/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Concerns/QueriesRelationships.php#L27-L62)).

[`getRelated()`](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/6c8371351a4d498eee273dbaa4a3b7182335a463/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Concerns/QueriesRelationships.php#L49) does the magic (adds the data to your relation). See that `join` does not do anything of this, it literally joins queries, nothing else related to relations. Also `join` comes from `Query/Builder` and any other method about relations comes from `Eloquent/Builder`.